# What's the source for the מעשה בר' אליעזר... שהיו מסובין of the הגדה?

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada

I'm making a דרשה related to פסח and I want to look up the source of **מעשה בר' אליעזר**, I don't know where it's located, is it in גמרא, does it even have a source besides of the הגדה?

> **מעשה בר' אליעזר ור' יהושע ור' אלעזר בן עזריה ור' עקיבא ור' טרפון, שהיו מסובן בבני ברק והיו מספרים ביציאת מצרים כל אותו הלילה, עד שבאו תלמידיהם ואמרו להם: רבותינו הגיע זמן קריאת שמע של שחרית**

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the haggadah is our only source for it

Comment: According to my local orthodox Rabbi who made a chart of the sources for several part of Magid, he said that this maase's source is Tosefta.

Comment: מעשה בר' אליעזר or אמר רבי אלעזר בן עזריה?

Comment: **מעשה בר' אליעזר**

Comment: See there the chapter בני ברק הקדומה.  https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A7

Comment: **@kouty** - What are you trying to say with this link? I checked it out, but it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This source isn't found anywhere in the same form (Daniel Goldschmidt says this in his haggadah). But compare [Tosefta Pesachim 10:8](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/f/f23.htm):

> מעשה ברבן גמליאל וזקנים שהיו מסובין בבית ביתוס בן זונין בלוד והיו [עסוקין בהלכות הפסח] כל הלילה עד קרות הגבר הגביהו מלפניהם ונועדו והלכו [להן] לבית המדרש